# Background placement between elements

Tags: css

i have question if it's possible to have that background from second div will be also visible inside my next div.

```
<div style="max-width:100%;width:100%;">
...
</div>
<div style="max-width:100%;width:100%; background:url('someimage.png')">
...
</div>
<div style="max-width:1200px; width:100%">
...
</div>
```

or i have to use image and position it absolute :

```
<div style="max-width:100%;width:100%;">
...
</div>
<div style="max-width:100%;width:100%;position:relative;z-index:2">
...
</div>
<img src="someimage.png" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:300px;z-index:1" />
<div style="max-width:1200px; width:100%;position:relative;z-index:2;">
...
</div>
```

but in the case of image i will not be able to position it properly relative to the second div.

unless there is another method ?

need something like this:
[image]

Comment: I can't understand your problem clearly, use picture or something please. :)

Comment: added image to show what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you want something like a watermark*

1. You need define `position` in div and img.
2. Img need be `position: absolute`.

You need define position in div and img.
Img need be position: absolute.
But If you want set background, better solution was [background-image property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image).

*Or like a card*

```
<style>
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
}

.card > img {
  padding-top: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Card</h2>

<div class="card">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:30%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Card]

*Or an hybrid solution*

```
<style>
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("img_avatar.png");
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4> 
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: background-image]

Comment: can't use it on body since we have in total 6 blocks  which should use shared backgrounds. each pair has own image some of them are even go over 3 blocks

Comment: Hum... do you want a card or similar? I will edit my answer. See if it helps!

Comment: yes something like a card, although i can't exactly wrap those 2 div's in another one..
guess will have to use for each image absolute position for each possible resolution.

Comment: Why not? To be responsive, you will need to "pack" in another div.

Comment: can't wrap it in div if image has to be shared between header / footer.

Comment: Inside the card? If yes, no problem. You can has a div with header and footer inside.